# How to add text inside the hole of the Donut Pie Chart in Grafana

Tags: plugins, grafana, pie-chart

I would like to add centered text in the middle of donut hole pie chart in Grafana like the image below

https://i.stack.imgur.com/XVAAg.png
I am using pie chart plugin of Grafana

Answer (score 0):

1. In file C:\Program Files\GrafanaLabs\grafana\data\plugins\piechart-panel\src\rendering.ts there is function "addPieChart".
2. Need to add these raws:

```js
let sumData = 0
    ctrl.data.forEach((elem: any) => {
      sumData = sumData + elem.data;
    });  //.reduce(reducer)
    const plotCanvas = $('<div><div style="position: absolute;left: 49%;top: 40%;z-index: 1000;"> '+ sumData + '</div></div>');
```

in line with:

```js
const plotCanvas = $('<div><div');
```